# C# Why is my control not accepting multiple keys in the KeyDown event

Tags: c#, user-controls

Ok guys so I've been working on this control for close to a month and one of the issues that I'm having is that if I press the CTRL key by it's self it registers and if I press the Space key by it's self it registers. I've tried to separate the two and I've tried to use them in the same `if` statement. Both are unsuccessful.

My first attempt was like this

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (_isEditing)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (_selectedObj != null)
                {
                    DeleteSelectedObject();
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.Control && e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
        {
            _isEditing = !_isEditing;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Now if I remove the Ctrl or the 'Space' key from the equation it works fine. So I tried to separate them and came up with

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (_isEditing)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (_selectedObj != null)
                {
                    DeleteSelectedObject();
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.Control)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            if (e.KeyData.Equals(Keys.Space))
            {
                _isEditing = !_isEditing;
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

using the `Console.WriteLine()` as a cheater to tell me when the key is pressed and the Ticks doesn't get displayed unless I Comment out the CTRL clause. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Quick and easy was what I was looking for and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get modifier in a KeyDown event. Rather try one of the following ways to know if modifiers (Ctrl, Shift, Alt) are pressed or not:

1. `Keyboard.IsKeyDown`

   ```
   if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))  
       &&  e.KeyData == Keys.Space){}
   ```
2. Check `Keyboard.Modifiers`

   ```
   if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        && e.KeyData == Keys.Space){}
   ```